# Can't establish HTTPS connection through VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services

In my company there is a project running the following:

(Client account) EC2 > Route53 > VPC Endpoint > (Server account) VPC Endpoint Service > NLB > EC2

They have an issue regarding HTTPS connections. The server's hosted zone is `foo.com`, and there is a certificate for `*.foo.com`. However, it's not possible to create a Route53 domain to the VPC Endpoint Service, so it needs to be created in the client account.

In the client account, the hosted zone is `bar.com`, and it's possible to create a record such as `server.bar.com` pointing to the VPC Endpoint.

So far so good, client can connect to server via `server.bar.com`.

Now the issue is about the certificate validation, as the client is connecting to `server.bar.com` but the certificate is for `*.foo.com`.

So, how can the client establish a HTTPS connection with the server through VPC Endpoint?

Comment: Are trying to use VPC Endpoint or AWS Privatelink ? because VPC endpoint is generally used to access AWS Services(For eg. to access a S3 from ec2 in private vpc) from VPC

Comment: @Kaneki21 for PrivateLink connections you need the VPC Endpoint Service on the "service provider" account, and a VPC Endpoint in the "consumer" account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging more into this topic, I'm going to answer my own question.

There might be different scenarios where one wants to establish a HTTPS connection using PrivateLink **between accounts**:

- Using AWS domains.
- Using an own domain.
- Requiring end to end encryption.

The first case is the easiest one that works out of the box. The service provider creates a VPC Endpoint Service, the consumer creates a VPC Endpoint, and then the consumer can access the service with `https://vpce-consumer.vpce-service.amazonaws.com`.

The second case is somewhat trivial as well, but requires a little more effort. The process is the same, but a private hosted zone has to be created in Route53, and then private domains have to be enabled in the settings of the VPC Endpoint Service. This way, we might assign a domain `example-service.com` to `vpce-service.amazonaws.com`, create a wildcard certificate for `*.example-service.com`, and finally, create an HTTPS listener in the NLB using this certificate. Now, when the consumer connects to `https://vpce-consumer.example-service.com`, the connection works.

The third one is like the second, but as we are talking about e2e, the TLS connection cannot be terminated in the NLB but in the host. So, we need to create a certificate for `*.example-service.com` with OpenSSL and install it the the host. Then, the listener in the NLB would be a standard TCP one instead of TLS.

So, where did the issues of these guys begin? They created a certificate with a Common Name of `foo.example-service.com`.

However, if they now tried to access the service with `https://vpce-consumer.vpce-service.amazonaws.com` or with a custom domain created in the consumer account pointing to that VPC Endpoint (e.g. `foo.example-consumer.com`), the client would report a SSL error because the domain and the certificate's domain don't match.

The workaround consisted in creating a new certificate, this time adding as Subject Alternative Name both `foo.example-consumer.com` and `vpce-consumer.vpce-service.amazonaws.com`. Now connections are end-to-end encrypted and trusted, because the certificate returned by the service is also valid for those domains.